# Primes related to the structure $\left| \pm a\pm b\pm c \right| $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $(a,b,c)$ be any coprime positive integers such that $a+b+c\neq 2x$ where $x$ is any integer

Let $${N_1,N_2,N_3,N_4}=\left| \pm a\pm b\pm c \right| $$

In most of the cases why is at least one of the four is a prime number?

for instance:

$(a,b,c)=(4,63,22)$ implies $(N_1,N_2,N_3,N_4)=(89,45,81,37)$

$(a,b,c)=(6,63,22)$ implies $(N_1,N_2,N_3,N_4)=(91,47,79,35)$

$(a,b,c)=(10,36,21)$ implies $(N_1,N_2,N_3,N_4)=(67,25,47,5)$

$(a,b,c)=(4,88,15)$ implies $(N_1,N_2,N_3,N_4)=(107,77,99,69)$

$(a,b,c)=(17,63,40)$ implies $(N_1,N_2,N_3,N_4)=(93,13,59,21)$

In a number of cases all the four numbers obtained are composite but the chance of such event is pretty thin as compared to the cases when at least one of the numbers is a prime. My question is, why does the numbers behave this way? What is the probability of the two cases?

Comment: Well, as an start requiring that every sum is odd biases the result(since $a+b+c$ is odd), and then requiring that every number is composite biases it again(a *for all* condition is way less likely than a *there exists*). I don't think there is more to it, but I will try to get some data about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already commented on by *chubakueno*, the requirements induce some bias towards having more primes. Having odd sum is required, or all sums would be even and the only possible prime would be 2; and had the three numbers had a common factor, the sum couldn't be prime either.

However, I suspect it all boils down to prime density. The prime density is $\approx 1/\ln x$, and if $a,b,c$ are of order of magnitude $\approx x$, the expected number of primes for purely random $a,b,c$ would be $\sim 4/\ln x$. Having ruled out even numbers doubles this to $8/\ln x$.

This means that for numbers $a,b,c$ of magnitude $3000$ or less, you're expected to get a prime merely as a consequence of the prime density. I suspect if you for every $(a,b,c)$ compute the expected number of primes in the sums list
$$
\frac{2}{\ln|a+b+c|}
+\frac{2}{\ln|a+b-c|}
+\frac{2}{\ln|a+c-b|}
+\frac{2}{\ln|b+c-a|}
$$
you will find this to be quite big even for very large numbers.